# Unexpected token export with Webpack 1.13 (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I webpack & babel to compile my react app.
In config, i have

(sorry, i'm forced to add it in a jsfiddle due too much code:
https://jsfiddle.net/tu5nnq7L/ )

and inside:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 52,
        "browsers": ["last 10 versions", "safari 7"]
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

But on a simple export var declaration, I have this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

```
export let toto = "test";
```

(same with import * as types from '../constants/Types' )

I dont understand why i have this error. Who can explain this ?

Thank you.

Comment: @Jayce444 my babelrc is inside my post ;-)
maybe do you wants all my webpack.config.js ?

Comment: Woops, yes I meant webpack.config.js lol

Comment: @Jayce444 I add it in https://jsfiddle.net/tu5nnq7L/

Comment: Ok I'll have a look. Do you have `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-env` installed in your `package.json` devDependencies?

Comment: Not in devDependencies, but in dependencies

Comment: In your question you say you get unexpected token error with `import * from..`, that's because that's not a valid import statement. You need to say `import * as Something from...`. You have to alias your import if you're going to import everything with an asterisk

Comment: Sorry, I write too quick this sentense.

I write:

import * as types from '../constants/Types'

but Chrome dont't like the *

Comment: Are you doing the importing/exporting within `.js` files? Or within `.jsx` files? (Asking cos you have ReactJS as a tag to the question)

Comment: If you trying to import/export within `.jsx` files, make sure to change the loader module from this: `test: /\.js?$/` to this: `test: /\.jsx?$/`

Comment: I try with jsx or js, same error ;-)
(all my file are in .js)

Comment: Ok well in the `module:loaders:include` array for `.js` files you have an array of paths. I'm assuming you're trying the importing/exporting from a file that's within one of those directories. If so, then I'm not sure what else to do lol, I can't see any other potential cause within your JSFiddle. Sorry :( Hopefully someone with more knowledge can help. Best of luck